# Difference between GIT_SSH/GIT_SSH_COMMAND/core.sshCommand?

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys

I am currently using GIT_SSH_COMMAND for a project but want to know the core Differences between GIT_SSH/GIT_SSH_COMMAND/core.sshCommand which one is better to use?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITSSHcode , https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coresshCommand

Comment: These are quite thoroughly covered in the documentation. What part of the documentation was unclear to you?

Comment: @torek The core implementational differences are not mentioned in the doc. 
Also for my project after npm update from npm 6 to npm 8 is facing issue and is not able to detect core.sshCommand instead I have to use GIT_SSH_COMMAND. Thus wanted to know core implementation chnage and how is it affected by npm updates

Comment: As far as I know, the only implementation difference is that `GIT_SSH` isn't run through the shell, and that is covered in the documentation (perhaps it needs more though, which was the point of the "which part(s) are unclear", although perhaps I phrased that too sharply). See also [bk2204's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72035771/1256452).

Answer (score 5):

`GIT_SSH` is the name of a program and cannot contain any arguments, nor is it passed to the shell.  `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` is passed to the shell and may contain any valid shell characters, including multiple arguments if you like.

`core.sshCommand` works just like `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`, but it is set in the config.  The environment variable overrides it.

My recommendation is to use the ones that pass data to the shell because they're easier to use and more flexible.  Note that you may need to set the variant (with `ssh.variant` or `GIT_SSH_VARIANT`) if your script or program is based around something other than OpenSSH or doesn't understand its full range of arguments.